# Java: Multiple class declarations in one file

Tags: java, class

In Java, you can define multiple top level classes in a single file, providing that at most one of these is public (see [JLS §7.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)).  See below for example.

1. Is there a tidy name for this technique (analogous to `inner`, `nested`, `anonymous`)?
2. The JLS says the system **may** enforce the restriction that these secondary classes can't be 'referred to by code in other compilation units of the package', e.g., they can't be treated as package-private.  Is that really something that changes between Java implementations?

e.g. PublicClass.java:

```
package com.example.multiple;

public class PublicClass {
    PrivateImpl impl = new PrivateImpl();
}

class PrivateImpl {
    int implementationData;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good questions. I've never really given the matter much thought, since it's almost never necessary to do this.

Comment: note that this is a vestigial feature; it would never have been possible if java had had nested classes from the beginning.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

My suggested name for this technique (including multiple top-level classes in a single source file) would be "mess". Seriously, I don't think it's a good idea - I'd use a nested type in this situation instead. Then it's still easy to predict which source file it's in. I don't believe there's an official term for this approach though.

As for whether this actually changes between implementations - I highly doubt it, but if you avoid doing it in the first place, you'll never need to care :)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the fact this answer is something that could be called "normative" (ie. "you should" instead of "in fact ... however ...") is the most likely reason for it to get a downvote I think. It doesn't actually answer any of the questions. Like raising an irrelevant exception instead of returning anything / raising an exception that has information about actual facts instead of opinions.

Comment: I found what I think is a minor exception to @JonSkeet 's suggestion to use a nested type (which I would otherwise agree with): if the main class is generic and the type parameter is the second class, the second class can't be nested. And if the two classes are tightly coupled (like PublicClass and PrivateImpl in the question), I think it's a good idea to put PrivateImpl as a top-level class in the same file.

Comment: I don't mean to resurrect anything too old but for someone stumbling upon this I want to clarify that its not always bad to have multiple classes within one file. This, as it seems to me, to be the core basis of component based programming. Similar to how Unity works when you call GetComponent, FindComponent, etc.

Comment: @BoomerRogers: No, this is definitely *not* the "core basis of component based programming". If you're programming against a component, why would you care how the source code is organized? (Personally I prefer dependency *injection* rather than the service locator pattern, but that's a different matter.) Separate API and source code organization in your mind - they're very different things.

Comment: @JonSkeet Even if it is bad practice, the fact is that java specs allow it. Also, this the topic regulary occurs in OCJP tests.

Comment: @JonSkeet Let me rephrase: Your "answer" is a personal irrelevant opinion. (i.e. answers like "mess" and "i doubt it" have little value.) So, your post does not answer any of the 2 posed questions. Check the answer of polygenelubricants, and you will see that he manages to answer both.

Comment: @bvdb: No, polygenelubricants doesn't answer the question of what it's called to specify multiple top-level classes in a single file. He described that `PrivateImpl` is a non-private top-level class, but that's not the same as describing the "technique" of having multiple top-level classes in a single file, which is what I believe the OP was asking. Interesting point about the 1.2.2-1.4 issue, although unfortunately the link is no longer useful. Of course, you're free to downvote (as I assume you did) but I don't see how the OCJP part is relevant at all.

Comment: @bvdb: (And there are *lots* of things which are bad practice but allowed by the spec. I would urge people not to write `public int[] foo(int x)[] { return new int[5][5]; }` as well, even though that's valid.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not saying that specs should describe good/bad practices. But the question was not : "can you tell me what is good practice?" If you strip your answer from all personal opinions there's just nothing left. And one reason why your opinion does not matter is the fact that even if we agree never to write this code, other people will (e.g. in an OCJP test). So, that's why we need a term for it, and why the whole matter of good/bad practice is out of scope of this question. So yes, that's why I (and many other people) downvoted.

Comment: @bvdb: So what do you believe the term *is* for this? (I don't believe we need a term for everything one could possibly have a term for.) I will clarify my answer to explain that I don't believe there *is* an official term for it.

Comment: @JonSkeet There's a simple rule: if you don't know the answer to a question, then don't reply to it.

Comment: @bvdb: "There is no such term" is an answer, and I still believe that to be the case. However, I think this conversation is unlikely to produce any further positive effects; this is my last comment in it.

Comment: In C# multiple types per file are allowed. This is not inherently messy at all. Do it when it makes sense and otherwise not. It makes sense for example for many trivial enum types or DTOs, JSON classes, generated code, etc.

Answer (score 160):

*Javac* doesn't actively prohibit this, but it does have a limitation that pretty much means that you'd never want to refer to a top-level class from another file unless it has the same name as the file it's in.

Suppose you have two files, `Foo.java` and `Bar.java`.

`Foo.java` contains:

- `public class Foo`

`Bar.java` contains:

- `public class Bar`
- `class Baz`

Let's also say that all of the classes are in the same package (and the files are in the same directory).

What happens if `Foo` refers to `Baz` but not `Bar` and we try to compile `Foo.java`? The compilation fails with an error like this:

```
Foo.java:2: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Baz
location: class Foo
  private Baz baz;
          ^
1 error
```

This makes sense if you think about it. If `Foo` refers to `Baz`, but there is no `Baz.java` (or `Baz.class`), how can *javac* know what source file to look in?

If you instead tell *javac* to compile `Foo.java` and `Bar.java` at the same time, or if you had previously compiled `Bar.java` (leaving the `Baz.class` where *javac* can find it), or even if `Foo` happens to refer to `Bar` in addition to `Baz`, then this error goes away. This makes your build process feel very unreliable and flaky, however.

Because the actual limitation, which is more like "don't refer to a top-level class from another file unless it either has the same name as the file it's in or you're also referring to another class that's named the same thing as that file that's also in that file" is kind of hard to follow, people usually go with the much more straightforward (though stricter) convention of just putting one top-level class in each file. This is also better if you ever change your mind about whether a class should be public or not.

Newer versions of *javac* can also produce a warning in this situation with `-Xlint:all`:

```
auxiliary class Baz in ./Bar.java should not be accessed from outside its own source file
```

Sometimes there really is a good reason why everybody does something in a particular way.

Comment: Does Maven do anything to make compilation reliable?

Comment: @Laurence You said _If Foo.java refers to Baz, but there is no Baz.java (or Baz.class), how can javac know what source file to look in?_ but even if I create a Baz.java, also then compiling Foo.java fails. It still does not know what source file to look in.

Comment: @KushalKumar javac will search the sourcepath, which defaults to the user classpath (which in turn defaults to the current directory). If your source is not rooted from a directory in your classpath, you'll need to specify your sourcepath.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Thanks. After reading a few times, I can understand it well. Except for when you say what the actual limitation is, *"don't refer to a top-level class from another file unless it has the same name as the file it's in or you're also referring to a class that's in that same file that's named the same thing as the file"* Could you please also explain this line?

Comment: @KushalKumar The point there is that the actual limitation is hard to follow. I reworded it slightly to try and make it more clear, but it really is a weird rule, and that's why in practice people use a variation that is easier to understand, but more strict.

Comment: @KushalKumar javac starts with the set of source files you specifically ask it to compile. When you refer to a class not in those sources it checks the classpath for compiled classes, and the source path *for source files with a matching name*. If it finds the latter, it adds it to the set of source files it's working on. So if you refer to Baz, and it's in the same file as Bar, javac will find Baz only because it pulled in Bar.java due to the reference to Bar.

Comment: @tapavko You say "this part is not true", but then quote a question, so I'm not sure what you think is "not true". The rest of what you said is correct, but none of it conflicts with what was said in the answer. I suggest you try creating the `Foo.java` and `Bar.java` as described in the answer, and then try compiling with the command `javac -d . Foo.java` without first compiling `Bar.java`. `javac` won't know where to find `Baz`, because there is no source or class file with that name.

Answer (score 25):

I believe you simply call `PrivateImpl` what it is: a `non-public top-level class`. You can also declare `non-public top-level interfaces` as well.

e.g., elsewhere on SO: [**Non-public top-level class** vs static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148686/non-public-top-level-class-vs-static-nested-class)

As for changes in behavior between versions, there was this discussion about something that "worked perfectly" in 1.2.2. but stopped working in 1.4 in sun's forum: [Java Compiler - unable to declare a non public top level classes in a file](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248432&tstart=2211).

Comment: My only issue with this is that you can have a `non-public top level class` be the only class in a file, so it doesn't address the multiplicity.

Comment: I understand the concern, but as you can see this is a terminology that others have historically used. If I have to make up my own term, I'll probably call it `secondary top level types`.

Comment: this is really a link-only answer, and now that link to sun forum doesn't work, there isn't much left

Answer (score 19):

You can have as many classes as you wish like this

```
public class Fun {
    Fun() {
        System.out.println("Fun constructor");
    }
    void fun() {
        System.out.println("Fun mathod");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fun fu = new Fun();
        fu.fun();
        Fen fe = new Fen();
        fe.fen();
        Fin fi = new Fin();
        fi.fin();
        Fon fo = new Fon();
        fo.fon();
        Fan fa = new Fan();
        fa.fan();
        fa.run();
    }
}

class Fen {
    Fen() {
        System.out.println("fen construuctor");

    }
    void fen() {
        System.out.println("Fen method");
    }
}

class Fin {
    void fin() {
        System.out.println("Fin method");
    }
}

class Fon {
    void fon() {
        System.out.println("Fon method");
    } 
}

class Fan {
    void fan() {
        System.out.println("Fan method");
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nenotlep When you do an "improve formatting", then please also take care that it doesn't messes with the code itself, like removing backslashes.

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

Just FYI, if you are using Java 11+, there is an exception to this rule: if you run your java file directly ([without compilation](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330)). In this mode, there is no restriction on a single public class per file. However, the class with the `main` method must be the first one in the file.

Answer (score 4):

> 1.Is there a tidy name for this technique (analogous to inner, nested, anonymous)?

Multi-class single-file demo.

> 2.The JLS says the system may enforce the restriction that these secondary classes can't be referred to by code in other compilation units of the package, e.g., they can't be treated as package-private. Is that really something that changes between Java implementations?

I'm not aware of any which don't have that restriction - all the file based compilers won't allow you to refer to source code classes in files which are not named the same as the class name. ( if you compile a multi-class file, and put the classes on the class path, then any compiler will find them )

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, with public static members on an outer public class, like so:

```
public class Foo {

    public static class FooChild extends Z {
        String foo;
    }

    public static class ZeeChild extends Z {

    }

}
```

and another file that references the above:

```
public class Bar {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Foo.FooChild f = new Foo.FooChild();
        System.out.println(f);

    }
}
```

put them in the same folder. Compile with:

```
javac folder/*.java
```

and run with:

```
 java -cp folder Bar
```

Comment: That example does not answer the question. You are giving an example of nested static classes, which is not the same as having two top level classes defined in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

According to Effective Java 2nd edition (Item 13):

> "If a package-private top-level class (or interface) is used by only
>   one class, consider making the top-level class a private nested class
>   of the sole class that uses it (Item 22). This reduces its
>   accessibility from all the classes in its package to the one class
>   that uses it. But it is far more important to reduce the accessibility
>   of a gratuitously public class than a package-private top-level class:
>   ... "

The nested class may be static or non-static based on whether the member class needs access to the enclosing instance (Item 22).

Comment: The OP Is not asking about nested classes.

Answer (score -16):

No. You can't. But it is very possible in Scala:

```
class Foo {val bar = "a"}
class Bar {val foo = "b"}
```