# declare multiple class using Eclipse

Tags: java

is there a way to declare 2 classes on the same .java file using Eclipse - also how the compiler will distinguish the .class for each declare class.

example

```
public class ThisTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }
}

class SimpleArray
{

}
```

thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Multiple class declarations in one file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly like your example.

The extra class need to be non-public

You could also define inner/nested classes. In this case you should investigate the difference

[Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

```
public class ThisTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }


    static class SimpleArray
    {

    }

    class SimpleArray2 {}
}
class Buddy {}
```

Each class will be located in an own .class file in a directory similar to the package.
Nested classes get its host prefixed and separated by an '$'.
The above case results in four class files

- ThisTest.class
- ThisTest$SimpleArray.class
- ThisTest$SimpleArray2.class
- Buddy.class

Just check the bin or classes folder of your eclipse project.

Comment: That is great Stefan !! thank you for help !! I wish I could vote but I can not !! thank you.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the second question though, regarding class file names.

Answer (score 3):

> *is there a way to declare 2 classes on the same .java file using Eclipse*

Yes, you can have several classes defined in a single .java file, but there may at most **one public** class in each file. (Just as in your example.)

Note that *if* you have a public class in a .java file, the name of that class must be the same as the name of the .java file.

> *how the compiler will distinguish the .class for each declare class.*

The names of the .class files does not depend on the name of the .java file, but on the identifiers of the class declarations.

If you have

```
class A {}
class B {}
```

in a file named `Classes.java`, you'll get `A.class` and `B.class` if you compile it.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is there is way to do that !! you can see  from the above code, Class thisTest is declare public and Class SimpleArray is a declared by default !!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation it is really helpful.. now that I have the 2 classes declared on the same file I got in compilation error "The public type Class ThisTest should be defined in its own file" ? any solution to this ?

Comment: Yes, *if* you have a public class, the name of that class must be the same as the .java file name.

Comment: @Sinan. This error means that the name of your .java file does not match the name of the public class. For your example above, the file MUST be called ThisTest.java