# is This Data Abstration Example right or not?

Tags: java

i had given the following code in an interview. I want to know whether it is right or not..

```
 public class DataAbstraction
    {
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            MyDetails obj = new MyDetails();
            obj.setNumebr(10);
            obj.incrementBy(20);
            int num = obj.getMumber();
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }

class MyDetails
{
    private int n;
    public void setNumebr(int i)
    {
        n = i;
    }
    public void incrementBy(int i)
    {
        n = n + i;
    }
    public int getMumber()
    {
        return n;
    }
}
```

So please check it and correct me if i was wrong

Comment: what is purpose of this code?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file

Comment: @HardikMishra, He only has one public class, no?

Answer (score 0):

There are many forms of abstractions in software. I would say that this is an example of data abstraction (though I would usually call it [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)). You could, if you would like to, change the member variable `n` to be of type... String(!), without changing the public interface of `MyDetails`.

Put differently: The details in the `MyDetails` class are *hidden* from the client code. The fact that `MyDetails` stores an `int` is *abstracted away* and it could be changed, for instance like this:

```
class MyDetails
{
    private String n;                // changed internal detail
    public void setNumebr(int i)
    {
        n = "" + i;
    }
    public void incrementBy(int i)
    {
        n = "" + getMumber() + i;
    }
    public int getMumber()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(n);
    }
}
```

Have a look at the Wikipedia article on data abstraction for further details:

- [Abstraction > Data abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Data_abstraction)

Comment: can you please elaborate more on your answer ?

Answer (score -1):

Since there aren't enough details in the question its guessing time again:

1) No, its wrong. it contains various spelling errors like "getMumber" and "setNumebr".

2) Yes, if we ignore the spelling errors the methods seem to do what one would expect from their names.

2) No, it doesn't launch the rocket and it doesn't scale to multi processor machines (assuming these where the requirements).