# Multiple classes in the same eclipse window

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm reading Thinking in Java and it's frustrating to declare each class in a separate window in Eclipse, as the examples often contain 6-7 very simple classes.

I can just make a new class file, make one class public in this class file and the others with default access, but I don't know what should be the class' name I created. For example, I do the following:

New -> Class -> and then I must choose a class name, let's say it's Dog.

Now, in this file, I have this:

```
public class Dog {
}
class Cat {
}
```

But since I have two classes, it's a little weird to have this class file (I don't know if it's the right word here?) to be named Dog in Eclipse (The name in the src folder).

Is there a better way to declare multiple classes in the same window(?) in Eclipse?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to have all classes be public, but IMO you should get in the habit of breaking up code appropriately now. This is how Java works; file names match the public class. You can also have multiple classes open and visible at the same time; why isn't that enough?

Comment: Agreed.  The convention of having (generally) once class per file exists for a reason.  As soon as you get to anything remotely complicated, you will wish you had that habit.  Inner classes?  different story, different argument.  But generally, having two classes in the same file is bad coding practice.

Comment: Yes , i know it's how it should be done. However, the examples in the book are just built so that they often have MANY very very simple classes . It gets a bit hard to follow these examples if i have to look at every file, often containing just a print statement. I'm aware it's not supposed to be in one file, but i'd just like to do the quite simple exercises in the book as comfortably as possible.

Comment: @geekkid If it's just a print statement then you don't need to look at it at all. Opening a class or method is a single keystroke; what's the big deal? You can't do what you're asking to and develop good habits at the same time.

Comment: For example, I am the sole developer for a project with 30 classes or so in 8 packages (thereabouts).  If I didn't have a separate file for each class, I would have NO idea how my code worked.  Each file has a separate class in it, which represents a separate object.  Think of the class file as a blueprint.  You don't want the Cat blueprints to be filed with instructions on how to make a dog, do you? (the answer is no)

Comment: Russell, i wasn't intending to make an inner Cat class in Dog, if that's what you're implying. I only wanted to know if there was a way to put multiple classes in the same WINDOW in eclipse, so i had a complete overview of all the very simple classes (ofter 7-8, containg one simple method with a print statement). It wouldn't be pretty if i had a complete project. with 1000 lines of code per class, outlined in a single window like this, ofcourse. But for my needs, it would be lovely.

Comment: @geekkid I don't understand why opening multiple views is so onerous.

Comment: You answered you question yourself `it's a little weird to have this class file to be named Dog`. `Dog` and `Cat` are both animals, so why would the `.java file` of the one 'contain' the definition of the other?

Comment: Dave, have you read Thinking in Java and typed these exercises in Eclipse? It would be much easier if i didn't have to declare new classes the way it's normally done in eclipse, via the interface. The exercises could be done in a minute, but with all the extra work, it more than doubles the time. I know, it's not a big deal, i just wondered if there was a way ..

Comment: A4L, it's illogical, i know. That's why i wanted to know if there is a feature in eclipse that let's you declare classes in the same window.

Comment: @geekkid You can create a new class with a few keystrokes. If you really want to wad everything into a great lump, then do so, it shouldn't require many changes to any of the book's code. I just don't think you should. You could also write them in a text editor and bust them out with a trivial shell script then open them normally in Eclipse.

Comment: DAve, the thing is though, the book's code too, is outlined in a single window in a single file.

Comment: @geekkid Don't know what else to tell you. You've gotten your answers. Maybe try a different IDE, maybe BlueJ can subvert Java conventions.

Comment: @geekkid I still can't understand what do you mean by `window` O_o ... `1` `Eclipse` == `1` `Window`  and `1` `.java file` == `1` `editor tab` in the same `Eclipse`, thus same `window`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the frustration are not genuine because:

1. This is the how Java is designed and makes all sense to define each
   class in a separate file. (Unless you want to write your own compiler)
2. You may want to use some shortcuts e.g.

   - Cntrl + Shift + R` to search a class
   - Alt + Shift + R to rename
   - You can update Eclipse to use shortcut for switching within classes.

Comment: I think i didn't form my question quite understandably. I don't want to have many classes in a file, i just want to declare multiple classes in the same Eclipse window, so i have a complete overview of them without clicking the tabs. But as i have been made aware, it's not possible :D . Thank you for the shortcuts and the answer in general !

Comment: @geekkid I still don't understand why you can't open multiple views: if you don't want them in the same file, then create new views. You can *view* as many files as you want, as multiple answers state.

Answer (score 2):

A java file can have at most only one public class into it. And the name of that file should be same as of that public class.

Comment: So what's your reasoning behind why I can have a public inner class, which is still a class, without problems?

Comment: @KyleM Because it's an inner class.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing isn't going to compile. Each top level java class must be declared in a file with the same name. It will give you an error "Cat must be declared in its own file" or something like that. If you really want to, you can put the Cat class inside of the Dog class, which is called an inner class. However since they aren't related classes you shouldn't do that. Just declare each one in its own file.

Comment: Or you can create a class called Animals and put all types (Dog, Cat, etc.) inside that class, but of course I prefer your approach.

Comment: @Quirin that could work, but I think you are forgetting of our good friend, the enum.

Comment: He's just starting out.  Let's not throw inheritance and polymorphism at him just yet :)

Comment: To add onto KyleM said, a fundamental rule should be in place. If I could source it, it would be great but I cba. You should only use nested classes when that class is used only in the containing class. Like the ArrayList iterator implementation.

Comment: @Legend yeah enum could be a good way, but I think it depends on task you should solve. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep each class in it's own position. If your class is small and data can be exposed you can consider using nested (inner) class.

By the way, in Eclipse you can show multiple class at same time. Just drag you file title to some place.

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question, rather than leave a bunch of comments stating why you shouldn't (which you seem to understand already), no.  There isn't really a better way to do what you want.  I don't know if it will compile or not (I seem to recall seeing that in the past in Java 5), but KyleM seems to think not so we'll go with that.

Short answer: no, there is not a better way to declare multiple classes in the same file.

(I don't want to suggest inner classes because that is kind of complicated for someone just starting java, as your post suggests).

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix Eclipse window with files, you can understand a .java file as a container for a java class. It's the standard way and it would help you to have a more clear project when it becomes bigger.

You can have more information about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file)

If you want 2 classes in the screen you can split the eclipse editor window by dragging the opened tab file and drop it on the tabs zone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you do have to do this the long way, as everyone else has suggested / insisted.  If the problem is a matter of clicking around through tabs, though, eclipse does allow you to drag tabs into new windows on the screen, which lets you view potentially all of them at once.

You also end up with an "overview" of the classes in the file explorer on the left of the screen, if that's more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Good luck (: