# Java: automatically creating a .class file for each class

Tags: java

Let's say I have a A.java with two classes (a public one and a private) both in the same file.

```
public class A{
    public static void main(string[] args){
        ...
    }
}

class B{
    ...
}
```

Why is Java automatically automatically creating a A.class and a B.class when compiling the A.java?

Is it to avoid this sort of problems? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336762/2034015

> What happens if Foo.java refers to Baz but not Bar and we try to
>   compile Foo.java? The compilation fails with an error like this:
>
> Foo.java:2: cannot find symbol symbol  : class Baz location: class Foo
>   private Baz baz;
>             ^ 1 error

Also, I know that the right way to work with Java is a file per class, but I wonder why Java does this.

Comment: java does this because it's a class-file per class, regardless of their public/private attributes. inner classes get called `outer$inner`, and anonymous classes get called `outer$number`.

Comment: Agreed, one class per file. The inner classes get the $ syntax, and require an instance of the preceding class to be instantiated before one of the type following the $ can be. (Inner classes require a reference to the containing type)

Comment: This is what javac does.  There are two classes, hence two class files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java works on the principle of .class files which are generated from your source code. You can have only one public class per file but many other classes (including inner/ anonymous / static etc. - inner classes have `$` in name preceded by outer class, anonymous have just numbers after `$`) in one file and still it will be compiled to more classes. So the relation would be  `source file` : `byte-code file` - `1 : n`.