# How do I create n-number exceptions in the same class?

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, custom-exceptions

ok, here's my problem.

I want to create my own custom exceptions such as 'UsernameAlreadyTakenException'. I can create a single class in a file which extends Exception. My problem is, I'd rather not have 3 - 5 different files for each 'subclass' that do almost nothing. I'd like to stick them all in the same file. Is this possible and if so how??

Comment: Just create those 3 - 5 separate files for each exception type. In Java programs, it's normal to have one class per file (and required for `public` classes). It's better to get over it than to try to do special tricks just because you want them in one file.

Comment: Why don't you want 3-5 different files?

Comment: I don't want multiple files, because it seems like a waste. Each class only consists of a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making a static sub class (though I don't necessarily recommend it).  Here's an example:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception2 {
        throw new Exception2();
    }

    public static class Exception1 extends Exception {

    }

    public static class Exception2 extends Exception {

    }

    public static class Exception3 extends Exception {

    }


}
```

Comment: Although I forgot the rule that @Sam brings up, what I'm saying here isn't "wrong" and could be a solution, so I don't see why it got a downvote.

Comment: I agree, your solution is perfectly valid

Comment: Plus,  this allows better control over access levels

Answer (score 2):

The only restriction against placing multiple classes inside the same file when compiling Java is that only one top-level class in the file can be marked `public`. This is because `public` classes must be in a file with the same name, and you can't have multiple classes with the same name.

It's usually a considered a poor practice, and it doesn't guarantee your classes will have the correct protection level, but you can just leave off `public` when declaring your additional classes. This will give them `default` protection.

For a good discussion on what default protection means (and the other protection levels), just see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215497/2175939) question.

So you could create the file `UsernameAlreadyTakenException.java` and put in it something like:

```
public class UsernameAlreadyTakenException extends Exception {
    ...
}
class MySecondException extends Exception {
    ...
}
...
class MyNthException extends Exception {
    ...
}
```

You could even name the file something else, but then you can't have the class `UsernameAlreadyTakenException` marked as `public`. But once again, it is [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336739/2175939) to do this. It's usually just better to have a new file for each distinct class.