# Can a .java file have multiple Classes and Interfaces?

Tags: java

Can a .java file have multiple classes (including the main) and interfaces inside it? Or do I have to put them in different .java files?

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple top-level classes or interfaces inside a Java source file. However, if one of them is `public`, the file must be named after that class. Therefore you can only have one `public` class in a Java source file.

Example of a Java source file containing multiple classes and interfaces:

```
package somepackage;

// note that main classes do NOT need to be public, as some people are saying.
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}

// multiple classes
class Class2 {
}

interface Interface1 {
}

// multiple interfaces
interface Interface2 {
}
```

You can also have inner classes/interfaces (even `public` ones), nested classes/interfaces (even `public` ones), and anonymous classes.

Answer (score 6):

**You can have multiple classes and interfaces in the same file** but the name of the file should be the class which is `public`.

> You can't have more than one `public` class in a file.

When ever you compile this file, class files for each class will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any number of classes in a java file . But the class with the `main()` method should be `public`.

So ,there can only be one `public` class per `.java` file, as public classes must have the same name as the source file. Still you can have any number of `private` class.

Also have a look at [Java: Multiple class declarations in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file)