# How to use another class in the same file path?

Tags: java

This is my first Java piece of code.

I have `AnotherClass` defined in anotherClass.java in this [fiddle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdF9BcTJncXk1Vzg):

Although both classes are in the same file path, the `HelloWorld` class is unable to access `AnotherClass`.

What have I done wrong?

I reproduce the code in the fiddle below:

HelloWorld.java:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        AnotherClass c = new AnotherClass();
     }
}
```

anotherClass.java:

```
public class AnotherClass {
    public AnotherClass() {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: `anotherClass` != `AnotherClass`.

Comment: And `Classe` != `Class`.

Comment: Make the first class public and then the other classes, below it, not public. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file

Comment: Also, don't use online compilers, or at least don't use the one provided by tutorialspoint. It is hiding the real error, which is `class AnotherClass is public, should be declared in a file named AnotherClass.java`