# Multiple records inside the same .java file

Tags: java, class, java-record, java-16

We can always have multiple classes inside a .java file. Considering encapsulation and that each class consists of multiple lines of code it always made sense to have 1 class (don't talk about nested classes) inside 1 .java file.

Now that records come into play and they can be as little as 1 line of code. Does it make sense to encapsulate multiple records inside the same .java class?

For example we could have

**DTO.java** file which would contain

```
record Employees(List<Employee> employees) { }  //This is just a wrapper class that we normally need in order to return a list of objects in rest web services
record Employee(String name, Integer age, List<Attribute> attributes){ }
record Attribute(String name, String value) { }
```

If no record has the public access modifier then we are allowed to contain all of them in a file with the name **DTO.java**

As I view it, it does not seem very good to have 3 .java files with only 1 line of code inside each one.

However we can still face issues like these described here [multiple classes inside same java file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336762/7237884)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right now there is no official way to do it.
As a workaround you could create an empty interface and put all your records inside, for example if your controller is CompanyController, I would create an interface called CompanyPort with all dto records inside

**CompanyPort.java**:

```
public interface CompanyPort {
      record Employees(List<Employee> employees) { } 
      record Employee(String name, Integer age, List<Attribute> attributes){ }
      record Attribute(String name, String value) { }
}
```

Hope that would help

Answer (score 8):

The facts that have not changed are:

1. You can not have more than one `public` class in a single `.java` file. However, you can have as many non-`public` classes in the same `.java` file as you wish.
2. The name of the `.java` file must be the same as the `public` class in it.
3. If none of the classes in a `.java` file is `public`, it can have any name.

**Note:** Since you have mentioned another answer in your question, I have included those classes as well in my demo just in case they can be helpful to join the dots.

***Attribute.java:***

```
import java.util.List;

public record Attribute(String name, String value) { }
record Employee(String name, Integer age, List<Attribute> attributes){ }
record Employees(List<Employee> employees) { }
```

***Bar.java:***

```
public class Bar {
    
}
class Baz {
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

***Foo.java:***

```
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Attribute attr1 = new Attribute("A", "X");
        Attribute attr2 = new Attribute("B", "Y");
        System.out.println(attr1);

        Employee e1 = new Employee("James", 23, List.of(attr1, attr2));
        System.out.println(e1);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("Boug", 21, List.of(attr2));

        Employees emps = new Employees(List.of(e1, e2));
        System.out.println(emps);

        Baz baz = new Baz();
        baz.hello();
    }
}
```

***Terminal commands:***

```
[~/Desktop/Record]: javac Bar.java
[~/Desktop/Record]: javac Attribute.java 
[~/Desktop/Record]: javac Foo.java 
[~/Desktop/Record]: java Foo
Attribute[name=A, value=X]
Employee[name=James, age=23, attributes=[Attribute[name=A, value=X], Attribute[name=B, value=Y]]]
Employees[employees=[Employee[name=James, age=23, attributes=[Attribute[name=A, value=X], Attribute[name=B, value=Y]]], Employee[name=Boug, age=21, attributes=[Attribute[name=B, value=Y]]]]]
Hello
```

Comment: 4. You can get problems with compilers/build tools or IDEs when they don’t know where to search for a particular class when the class whose name determined the file name has not been referenced

Answer (score 8):

In this case, since the records are related, you can do the equivalent thing to having static inner classes in a standard class - i.e.:

```
public record Employees(List<Employee> employees) {
    public record Employee(String name, Integer age, List<Attribute> attributes) {}
    public record Attribute(String name, String value) {}
}
```

The consumer will, as they did before records, access the sub-records as

```
Employees.Employee employee;
Employees.Attribute attribute;
```