# Trying to run a java source file but java cannot find main class

Tags: java

The following java class will compile, but trying to run it cannot find main.

```
class Box {

    double width;
 
    double height;

    double depth;

} 
class BoxDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Box mybox = new Box();

        double vol;

        mybox.width = 10;

        mybox.height = 20;

        mybox.depth = 15;

        vol = mybox.width * mybox.height * mybox.depth;

        System.out.println("Volume is " + vol);

    }

}
```

> error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Box

I compiled it no problems but it will not run using `java BoxDemo.java`

keep getting this error

> error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Box

Comment: Your class `Box` doesn't have a method called main. You defined that in `BoxDemo`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Your title should be a very short summary of the issue you're having.

Comment: You need to declare BoxDemo before Box, otherwise it checks Box for the main method.

Comment: Maybe this should be reopened. It's a bit obscure, you can have 2 classes in a file, but it tries to run the first class when using single file mode.

Comment: Here's an answer, but the question is different. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59456989/2067492

Comment: Try with `javac BoxDemo.java` and then `java BoxDemo`.

Comment: Note, if you compile your file you'll be left with two .class files. You can run the file by calling `java BoxDemo` notice I leave off the .java

Answer (score 4):

When you type `java BoxDemo.java` it tries to *run your .java file* in that case the first class defined in the .java file is checked for a main method. Since you put Box above BoxDemo then it checks box for a main method.

As defined in the [jep330](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330) it runs the first class it finds in the source file. This is to offer some flexibility in the name of the files and the usage.

There are two fixes for this.

1. Put Box below BoxDemo in the source file.
2. Compile the source and then run the resulting class.

   javac BoxDemo.java
   java BoxDemo

Notice the lack of .java at the end.