# Is there any difference between these two classes?

Tags: java

I know we can create multiple classes inside another class with the only restriction that only one public class is allowed in one source file.

```
package xyz;
public class TheClass{ 
 class SomeClass{ 
     } 
} 
class AnotherClass { }
```

But is there any difference between the **SomeClass** and **AnotherClass** here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148686/non-public-top-level-class-vs-static-nested-class

Comment: Not covered in the dupe (I think) is the fact that `AnotherClass` is just a non-public class.